# How to fetch an index using id?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

i am tring to get i random id then with i am trying to get index of WORDTR and WORDEN but not able to do so.please help me out.

```
public class DatabeseHelper  extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public DatabeseHelper(Context c){
    super(c,"WORDS",null,1);

    SQLiteDatabase db =this.getWritableDatabase();

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String sql="create table WORDS(ID integer primary key autoincrement,WORDTR TEXT,WORDEN TEXT)";
    db.execSQL(sql);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)     {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS WORDS");
    onCreate(db);
}

public Cursor getDataRandom(){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from ID ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1 ",null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("ID"));


    return cursor;
```

Comment: @Kaizaki have you checked your database is created or not.?

Comment: @Tauqir i want to opposit one. get row from id.but thank a lot for comment.

Comment: @PankajMundra yes cheked its working.

Comment: @KAIZAKI check and try my answer below.

Comment: @KAIZAKI and let me know if it not works.

Comment: @PankajMundra its worked.

Comment: Glad to help my friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public DatabeseHelper(Context c){
    super(c,"WORDS",null,1);

    SQLiteDatabase db =this.getWritableDatabase();

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String sql="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + WORDS+
    "( " +
    "ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL UNIQUE, " +
    "WORDTR  TEXT, WORDEN TEXT);";

    db.execSQL(sql);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS WORDS");
    onCreate(db);
}
```

public int getDataRandom(){

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from WORDS ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1 ",null);
     if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

    int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("ID"));

 } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    return id;
```

Answer (score 1):

The table name is "WORDS" when you created the table .But you are trying to fetch the data from table name "ID" which does not exist anywhere.

The correct code is

```
public Cursor getDataRandom(){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from WORDS ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1 ",null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("ID"));


    return cursor;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have many mistakes in code, see the below code with comments

public class DatabeseHelper  extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
public DatabeseHelper(Context c){
    super(c,"WORDS",null,1);
   // SQLiteDatabase db =this.getWritableDatabase();

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String sql="create table WORDS(ID integer primarykey autoincrement,WORDTR TEXT,WORDEN TEXT)";
    db.execSQL(sql);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS WORDS");
    onCreate(db);
}
```

Select random data.

```
    public Cursor getDataRandom(){

            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

           // select * from WORDS not a ID
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from WORDS ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1 ",null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            // id is not used,not need to declare
            int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("ID"));


           // return a id not a cursor
            return cursor;
    }
```